# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I've been trying to use StandarScaler() for scaling data using csv dataset

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', nrows=50000)
data.head()

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(data)

scaled_data = scaler.transform(data)

scaled_data.head()
```

When i run the code i always get the same error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_13244/2182372482.py in <module>
----> 1 scaled_data.head()

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because NumPy arrays don't have a `head()` method. You could try converting it to a Pandas dataframe afterwards, something like this:

```
scaled_data_df = pd.DataFrame(scaled_data, columns=data.columns)

scaled_data_df.head()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @LucasHill but when I entered and ran the code there was a new error



**
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'number-of-columns' was passed
**

Comment: Sorry, that was meant to be a stand-in for the actual number of columns. Did some research, and columns=data.columns should work.